# Is it possible to write on top of a buffer?

Tags: go

```
buff := bytes.NewBuffer(somebytes)
```

How to write on top of `buff`? Currently I'm creating a new buffer. Is this the right way?

```
newBuff := bytes.NewBuffer(otherbytes) 
newBuff.ReadFrom(buff)
```

Comment: You want to start with `somebytes` and add (write) more bytes to it?

Comment: In my code I actually have only "buff" ; somebytes being the result of buff itself ( buff.Bytes) thus the reason why I was wondering if I could use only one buffer or I need two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) returns a [`*Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer). `*Buffer` implements [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) (and [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)) so you can simply write to it by calling its [`Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Write) or [`WriteString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteString) methods.

Example:

```
somebytes := []byte("abc")
buff := bytes.NewBuffer(somebytes)
buff.Write([]byte("def"))
fmt.Println(buff)
```

Output as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xOcspXoNel)):

```
abcdef
```

If you want to start with an empty buffer, you can simply create an empty `Buffer` struct (and take its address):

```
buff := &bytes.Buffer{}
```

If you want to "overwrite" the current content of the buffer, you can use the [`Buffer.Reset()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Reset) method or the equivalent [`Buffer.Truncate(0)`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Truncate) call.

Note that resetting or truncating the buffer will throw away the content (or only a part of it in case of `Truncate()`. But the allocated buffer (byte slice) in the background is kept and reused.

**Note:**

What you really want to do is not possible directly: just imagine if you want to insert some data in front of an existing content, the existing content would have to be shifted every time you write / insert something in front of it. This is not really efficient.

Instead create your body in a `Buffer`. Once it's done, you will know what your header will be. Create the header in another `Buffer`, and when it's done, copy (write) the body (from the first `Buffer`) into the second already containing the header.

Or if you don't need to store the whole data, you don't need to create a 2nd `Buffer` for the header. Once the body is ready, write the header to your output, and then write the body from the `Buffer`.

Comment: The question is how to write "def" on top of "abc".

Comment: My use case is that I write various data and also keep track of the "dependencies" after each write. After   I write all the "body" parts I need to write the header with all the dependencies on top of the body (buffer).

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat So you want to insert the header before the body? Or the space for the header is reserved and you want to fill it later (after body has been written)?

Comment: The structure is "[header][bodypart][bodypart]". However I know the header only after I've written the body parts so it may also be said  that I need to basically to "reserve" space for header and then fill it later after the body is written. However as I said the header size is not known until the body is written.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat In this case I would suggest to write the body to a `Buffer`, and once it's done, you can write the header to the output where everything should go, and after header is written, write the Body. I assume there is something missing that prevents this to be enough for you. Why isn't this working/good for you?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat See the edit which addresses your body-first, header-second task.